# how to create trigger functions in PostgresSQL for multiple schemas and tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

How to create trigger functions in PostgresSQL for multiple schemas and tables.

I need a single function for multiple tables and schemas.

am trying the code below.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_modifiedUser(pSchemaName text, pTableName text)
                RETURNS  trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
vUserid   numeric;
BEGIN
                select t.userid into vUserid from public.user_login_details t where inet (t.systemid) = inet_client_addr() order by t.id desc limit 1;
                UPDATE pSchemaName||.||pTableName SET modified_user = vUserid ,modified_date = now() WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
                RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_modUser_aerial
  BEFORE UPDATE OF geom
  ON sandiego.aerial
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.update_modifiedUser('sandiego','aerial');
```

while running the function I am getting this error:

> ERROR:  trigger functions cannot have declared arguments
>
> HINT:  The arguments of the trigger can be accessed through TG_NARGS
>   and TG_ARGV instead.
>
> CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "update_modifieduser" near
>   line 1

let me know any changes in my function

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamic query in trigger function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116111/dynamic-query-in-trigger-function-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

I in your place would `SET search_path` appropriately in the function body, then you don't need to schema qualify the objects inside your function and can work without much dynamic SQL.

You can get the schema of the table from the `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` variable, or you can pass it as argument to the trigger function in `CREATE TRIGGER` and read it from `TG_ARGV[]`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER).